# Strange exception on injection of primitive via Spring @Value annotation

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, aspectj

I have strange error on attempt to inject int primitive via Spring @Value annotation (Spring version 3.2.13). Short description: Spring is trying to inject bean of primitive type (int in my case) instead of primitive itself.

- I have property file "myProps.properties" with property

  ```
  number.of.search.log.events.in.queue=4
  ```
- Configuration class on scanned path with content

  ```
  @Configuration
  @ComponentScan(basePackages = {
          "com.search.log"
  })
  @PropertySource("classpath:myProps.properties")
  @EnableAspectJAutoProxy
  public class SearchLogConfiguration {

      @Bean
      public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer  propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
          return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
      }

  }
  ```
- Aspect where primitive should be injected

  ```
  @Aspect
  @Component
  public class SearchLogAspectHandler {

      @Value("${number.of.search.log.events.in.queue:2}")
      public int numberOfSearchLogEventsInQueue;
  ...
  }
  ```

Every time on application start I got this exception:

```
Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: public int numberOfSearchLogEventsInQueue; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [int] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value(value=${number.of.search.log.events.in.queue})}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:298)
```

Also primitives can't be injected into other beans as well.

Question: Please, help to find out why Spring can't inject primitive, but instead is trying to inject bean of type [int] and can't found one.

Comment: Which version of Spring? 3.0.5 had a bug that might be causing this: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-8574

Comment: Do you have a `PropertySourcePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` configured?

Comment: Yes, it is configured, but result it the same

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56030501/spring-value-annotation-not-working-in-constructor try this its working

Answer (score 0):

Change `@PropertySource("classpath:applicationConfig.properties")` into `@PropertySource("classpath:myProps.properties")` or use `@PropertySources` annotation.

Comment: Thank you for comment, my mistake - in both cases myProps.properties are used. Unfortunately it is not source of bug