# how to use constructor autowried

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, autowired

I can get it working using field autowired.

```
@Component
public class ZMyServiceConstructor {

   @Autowired
   private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Value("${my_test_property}")
    private String url;

}
```

I'd like to use constructor autowried. When I don't add any construtor, or I use either @NoArgsConstructor or @RequiredArgsConstructor, url has value. But **restTemplate is null**

```
@Component
//@NoArgsConstructor 
//@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ZMyServiceConstructor {

   private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Value("${my_test_property}")
    private String url;

}
```

If I use @AllArgsConstructor, it gives me error:

```
required a bean of type 'java.lang.String' that could not be found
```

How to get this working?

**Updated**:

1. Adding final to field restTemplate for lombok to build a constructor
2. @Value can't be used in final field. The field will be injected after constructor is called. [@Value annotation not working in constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56030501/value-annotation-not-working-in-constructor)

   ```
   @Component
    @RequiredArgsConstructor
    public class ZMyServiceConstructor {

       private final RestTemplate restTemplate;

       @Value("${my_test_property}")
       private String url;

    }
   ```

This equals to below

```
@Component
public class ZMyServiceConstructor {

    private final RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Value("${my_test_property}")
    private String url;

    @Autowired
    public ZMyServiceConstructor(RestTemplate restTemplate) {
        this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two problems here

First:

You're trying to use RestTemplate without building one
Try to build your restTemplate like this:

```
@Configuration
public class RestTemplateConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplateBuilder() {
        return new RestTemplateBuilder().build();
    }
}
```

Second:

You're using Lombok's constructors wrong.
Try this:

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ZMyServiceConstructor {
    private final RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Value("${my_test_property}")
    private final String url;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a @Configuration class where you define your RestTemplate bean.
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/spring-resttemplate-example.

Also you should use @RequiredArgsConstructor and use private final RestTemplate restTemplate. It seems like your problem with @AllArgsConstructor is that spring boot is trying to inject your String attribute with a bean that (for obvious reasons) can´t be found.